# Getting data from jquery loop in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form in which I am adding new rows in one of the div through jquery

```html
<div class="packs">
  <div>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="pname" id="pname" value="Test" />
     <img class="add-icon" src="media/icon/add.png" height="30" width="30">
  </div>
</div>
```

In jquery, I am doing this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
  $(".packs").on('click', '.add-icon', function () {
     $(".packs").append('<div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="pname" id="pname" value="Test" /><img class="add-icon" src="media/icon/add.png" height="30" width="30"></div>');
  });
});
```

What I need is to get array of all the elements which I have added. 
`$_POST['pname']` is returning only last entered element.

Can someone suggest what to do here.

Comment: You must ask more precise question. Array of what? You need to store this array in JS or PHP?

Comment: All rows with id="pname". This data will be stored in database through php. This is not an ajax query, and I need data of all the rows together when I submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store in database I assume that you submit this form at the end of filling in.

Then you should add indices to the individual rows. You will get array under variable `$_POST['pname']`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      
    let id_no = 0;
    $(".packs").on('click', '.add-icon', function () {
        id_no += 1;
        $(".packs").append('<div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="pname[' + id_no + ']" class="pname" value="Test" /><img class="add-icon" src="media/icon/add.png" height="30" width="30"></div>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="packs">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="pname[0]" id="pname" value="Test" />
        <img class="add-icon" src="media/icon/add.png" height="30" width="30">
    </div>
</div>
```